# Iteratively Declare Unique Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I'm trying to do is declare a series of arrays with unique names (e.g. DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5,...,DTn).

```
    for(i=1; i<=length; i++){
        var currentLoop = "DT" + i;
        this[currentLoop].push(time);
    }
```

Is there a way to iteratively create arrays so that I don't have to declare each array myself? Is there a way I can force "DT" + i to become an array?

Comment: You mean like `this[currentLoop] = [time]` ? They ultimately need to be declared manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to your approach

```
var dtArrays = {};
var arrayTotal = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < arrayTotal; i++){
 dtArrays["DT"+i] = [];
}
```

and then later if you wanted to modify or use one just access it as such

```
dtArrays["DT5"].push("hello");
var message = dtArrays["DT5"][0];//"hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use objects if the indexes are not increased.

```
//obj
var list = {};

for(i=1; i<=length; i++){
    var currentLoop = "DT" + i;
    list[currentLoop] = time;
}

//arr
var listDT = [];

for(i=1; i<=length; i++){
    listDT.push(time);
}
```